# Convert DataFrame String colum to Timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying the following code to convert a string date column to a timestamp column:

```
val df = Seq(
    ("19-APR-2019 10:11:10"),
    ("19-MAR-2019 10:11:10"),
    ("19-FEB-2019 10:11:10")
  ).toDF("date")
  .withColumn("new_date", to_utc_timestamp(to_date('date, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"), "UTC"))

  df.show
```

It almost works but it lost hours

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|                date|           new_date|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|19-APR-2019 10:11:10|2019-04-19 00:00:00|
|19-MAR-2019 10:11:10|2019-03-19 00:00:00|
|19-FEB-2019 10:11:10|2019-02-19 00:00:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Do you have any idea or any other solution?

Comment: You can use `to_timestamp` instead of `to_utc_timestamp+to_date`. Like `df.withColumn("new_date", to_timestamp('date, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as SMaz mentioned in comment, followings lines do the tick:

```
import org.apache.sql.functions.to_timestamp

df.withColumn("new_date", to_timestamp('date, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```